# How do I use this function without the need for adding in a text?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to figure out a way to allow the inline buttons without the need of the last line with the message, I just want the buttons to appear right below the "Please select the date you wish to book an appointment with us."

I have pretty much googled for a few hours but have not seem to find a solution to my wants.

```
async def reserve(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Please select the date you wish to book an appointment with us.")
    keyboard = [
        [
            InlineKeyboardButton("Week 1", callback_data = "DATE"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Week 2", callback_data = "DATE"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Week 3", callback_data = "DATE"),
            InlineKeyboardButton("Week 4", callback_data = "DATE"),
        ]
    ]
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    await update.message.reply_text("October", reply_markup = reply_markup)
```

Comment: Please replace the image link with your formatted code as it will help provide more accurate and helpful answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) does not include any functionality that allows to send buttons that are not attached to a messsage.

Comment: Ah that sucks, so I would need to have the “October” text right?